# Possible improvements in clojure "official" concurrency example (using locks,atoms,stm)

Tags: performance, concurrency, clojure, jvm, stm

i am trying to get [the "official" example of clojure concurrency](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming) closer to a java version using manual locking. [In this gist](https://gist.github.com/3712560) i put the java and clojure code and the thread dump of a VisualVm profile of all versions. 
Here it is the clojure code and timing

```
(ns simple-example (:gen-class))
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
;; original from: http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming
(import '(java.util.concurrent Executors Future)
SimpleLocking$Node)

(defn test-concur [iter refs nthreads niters]
  (let [pool (Executors/newFixedThreadPool nthreads)
        tasks (map (fn [t]
                      (fn []
                        (dotimes [n niters]
                          (iter refs t))))
                   (range nthreads))]
    (doseq [^Future future (.invokeAll pool tasks)]
      (.get future))
    (.shutdown pool)))

(defn test-stm [nitems nthreads niters]
  (let [refs (vec (map ref (repeat nitems 0)))
        iter #(dosync (doseq [r %] (alter r + 1 %2)))]
    (test-concur iter refs nthreads niters)
    (map deref refs)))

(defn test-atom [nitems nthreads niters]
  (let [refs (vec (map atom (repeat nitems 0)))
        iter #(doseq [r %] (swap! r + 1 %2))]
    (test-concur iter refs nthreads niters)
    (map deref refs)))

;; SimpleLocking$Node is the class with the synchronized method of java version
(defn test-locking [nitems nthreads niters]
  (let [refs (->> (repeatedly #(SimpleLocking$Node.))
                    (take nitems) vec)
        iter #(doseq [^SimpleLocking$Node n %] (.sum n (+ 1 %2)))]
    (test-concur iter refs nthreads niters)
    (map (fn [^SimpleLocking$Node n] (.read n)) refs)))

(definterface INode
  (read [])
  (add [v]))

(deftype Node [^{:unsynchronized-mutable true} value]
  INode
  (read [_] value)
  (add [this v] (set! value (+ value v))))

(defn test-locking-native [nitems nthreads niters] 
  (let [refs (->> (repeatedly #(Node. 0))
          (take nitems) vec) 
    iter #(doseq [^Node n %]
          (locking n (.add n (+ 1 %2))))]
    (test-concur iter refs nthreads niters)
    (map (fn [^Node n] (.read n)) refs)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (read-line)
  (let [[type nitems nthreads niters] (map read-string args)
    t #(apply + (time (% nitems nthreads niters)))]
    (case type
      'lock (println "Locking:" (t test-locking)) 
      'atom (println "Atom:" (t test-atom))
      'stm (println "STM:" (t test-stm))
      'lock-native (println "Native locking:" (t test-locking-native)))))
```

Time (in an "old" intel core duo):

```
Java version
int nitems=100;
int nthreads=10;
final int niters=1000;
Sum node values: 5500000
Time: 31

simple-example=> (-main "lock" "100" "10" "1000")
"Elapsed time: 60.030324 msecs"
Locking: 5500000
nil
simple-example=> (-main "atom" "100" "10" "1000")
"Elapsed time: 202.309477 msecs"
Atom: 5500000
nil
simple-example=> (-main "stm" "100" "10" "1000")
"Elapsed time: 1830.568508 msecs"
STM: 5500000
nil
simple-example=> (-main "lock-native" "100" "10" "1000")
"Elapsed time: 159.730149 msecs"
Native locking: 5500000
nil
```

NOTE: I dont want get a clojure version as fast as java one, or a stm version as fast as clojure using locks one. I know that is in general difficult and with some problems impossible. I know the use of atoms and stm is more composable,easier to use and less error prone than using manual locks. Those version are only the best possible referents in java and clojure for the problem (well i did my best).
My objective is get the atom and stm versions closer to locking ones, or to understand why (maybe in this concrete example) is not possible to speed up those versions.

NOTE: Another comparation, this time with haskell versions using STM and MVars (code in same gist linked):

```
>SimpleExampleMVar 100000 1000 6
Starting...
2100000000
Computation time: 11.781 sec
Done.

>SimpleExampleSTM 100000 1000 6
Starting...
2100000000
Computation time: 53.797 sec
Done.

>java -cp classes SimpleLocking
Sum node values: 2100000000
Time: 15.703 sec

java -cp classes;%CLOJURE_JAR% simple_example lock 1000 6 100000
"Elapsed time: 27.545 secs"
Locking: 2100000000

java -cp classes;%CLOJURE_JAR% simple_example lock-native 1000 6 100000
"Elapsed time: 80.913 secs"
Native locking: 2100000000

java -cp classes;%CLOJURE_JAR% simple_example atom 1000 6 100000
"Elapsed time: 95.143 secs"
Atom: 2100000000

java -cp classes;%CLOJURE_JAR% simple_example stm 1000 6 100000
"Elapsed time: 990.255 secs"
STM: 2100000000
```

Comment: Clojure's canonical concurrent programming constructs are tools for compromising performance in order to achieve good abstractions that have consistent semantics everywhere. Manual locking that is correctly implemented will be faster almost every time, but it is usually harder to get the locking semantics right than to use Atoms/Refs/Agents right.

Comment: The question is somewhat related with this one (a haskell version): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475363/speed-up-haskell-concurrency

Comment: @animal I am aware of that tradeoff but imo the diff between stm and atoms or locking is too large. Maybe the problem is not suitable for the optimistic STM?

Comment: I think a significant source of the problem is that SimpleLocking$Node gets to go on a faster path than an atom ever can. The SimpleLocking$Node has a fixed operation of incrementing by x that's under synchronized access. With Atoms, the initial value has to be read, the new value calculated by the fn passed to swap!, and then an atomic compare and swap operation needs to be executed successfully. Contention on a SimpleLocking$Node leads to threads blocking. Contention on an atom leads to the alteration fn needing to be called repeatedly. The latter can't compete with the former.

Comment: There's two ways to get a more apples to apples comparison: make SimpleLocking$Node accept a runnable, read it's value, apply the runnable to its value, then CAS against the read value. Alternatively since none of the threads modifying the contended resource ever read it directly and only push alterations to it, it's a good candidate for agents, which should get performance nearish the synchronization scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really comparing like with like here - the Clojure versions are creating and swapping in new immutable boxed numbers whereas the Java version is just bumping a mutable primitive `int` counter in a synchronised method.

You can do normal Java-style manual locking in Clojure with something like:

```
(locking obj (set! (. obj fieldName) (+ 1 (.fieldName obj)))))
```

The `locking` construct is effectively equivalent to a Java `synchronized` code block.

If you do this with either a type-hinted Java object or a Clojure deftype with an `:unsynchronized-mutable` field then I think you should be able to match pure Java synchronized performance.

Haven't tested this but I think it should work with primitives as well (which might be useful if you are incrementing `long` counters etc.)

Comment: I am not sure the main problem is related with boxing numbers (although it adds some overhead). Reviewing cpu profiles you can see the atom version does 2007778 add calls, the stm verion 2852124 and the locking version (both java and clojure) 1000000 fixed calls. Also the stm version spends more time in blocking threads than others. Maybe this concrete problem (official!) provokes too much collisions and retries.